# FCGIApp+Nginx+Lazarus+Debian

Tags: nginx, debian, lazarus, fastcgi

Всем доброго времени суток!
У меня поступило задание написать FastCGI-приложение на Lazarus и заставить его работать в связке с Nginx на Debian. Что сделал я...

1. Обновил FPC и Lazarus до последних версий через fpcupdeluxe.
2. Установил пакет fpweb в Lazarus и создал тестовое FastCGI-приложение (код ниже)

   ```
    program fcgitest;
   ```

   {$mode objfpc}{$H+}

   uses
   fpFCGI, unitmain;

   begin
   Application.Title:='FCGITest';
   { Uncomment the port setting here if you want to run the
   FastCGI application stand-alone (e.g. for NGINX) }

   Application.Port:=9000; // For example
   Application.Initialize;
   Application.Run;
   end.

   unit unitmain;

   {$mode objfpc}{$H+}

   interface

   uses
   SysUtils, Classes, httpdefs, fpHTTP, fpWeb;

   type

   { TFPWebModuleMain }

   TFPWebModuleMain = class(TFPWebModule)
   procedure DataModuleRequest(Sender: TObject; ARequest: TRequest;
   AResponse: TResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
   private

   public

   end;

   var
   FPWebModuleMain: TFPWebModuleMain;

   implementation

   {$R *.lfm}

   { TFPWebModuleMain }

   procedure TFPWebModuleMain.DataModuleRequest(Sender: TObject;
   ARequest: TRequest; AResponse: TResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
   begin
   AResponse.ContentType := 'text/html;charset=utf-8';
   AResponse.Contents.Add('Hello World!');
   Handled:=true;
   end;

   initialization
   RegisterHTTPModule('TFPWebModule1', TFPWebModuleMain);
   end.

Скомпилировалось все отлично.

3. Установил Nginx 1.18.0 штатно через apt-get. Написал конфиг для виртуального хоста (ниже)

   server {
   listen 80;
   server_name debiantest.local www.debiantest.local;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/debiantest.local.access.log main;
   root   /var/www/debiantest.local;

   ```
    location / {
        #include          /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER        $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

        fastcgi_pass  localhost:9000;
        }
   ```

   }
4. Для запуска  FCGI-приложения через SystemD написал unit (ниже). Не совсем уверен, что правильно, но запускается руками нормально и на порте 9000 висит. Это видно через Nettat.

   [Unit]
   Description=FCGITest
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   User = www-data
   Group = www-data
   ExecStart=/opt/fcgitest/fcgitest
   Restart = always
   RemainAfterExit=yes
   TimeoutSec=25

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
5. А проблема, собственно, заключается в исключении при обращении к локальному сайту...
   [image: Скрин ошибки]

Из ошибки можно сделать вывод, что Nginx отработал, отдал запрос,  а приложение по каким-то причинам этот запрос не может обработать и генерирует исключение. Полазил я по исходникам fcl-web и нашел, что оно  может происходить в TWebHandler.HandleRequest(...) модуля custweb, если не ошибаюсь... Глубже не полез. Не совсем понятно что "не найдено"-то... Судя по всем мануалам, должен отработать дефолтовый web-модуль, а у него (видно из кода выше) только один обработчик на все запросы. Не подскажете, то я делаю не так?

Вдогонку. Попробовал helloworld из fcl-webсобрать (но не через makefile, а так) - собралось, но при выполнении та же ошибка. Может что-нибудь не доустановил просто в систему или не все настроил. Кто сталкивался -  подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашел сам:
Application.Legacyrouting := True;